# Calling a Function (int function with char parameter)

Tags: c

How do I call a function (`int PlayGuess(char solution)`) in my `main` function?
Would I declare a `char` or `int` to get the `PlayGuess` function into `main`?

Comment: Would you provide us your code or some snippet of it?

Comment: Pass a `char` to the function and store the return value in an `int`

Comment: Declare a char or use a char literal like 'a' or 5 for the call like this: `PlayGuess(7);'.

Comment: I would go to the bookstore - buy book on C - read it

Comment: I read the book however it doesnt REALLY explain how to do this. I dont have an issue when its my own variables, functions etc but its an assignment where my professor gives certain functions and we have to make it work while declaring our own variables and its just a big mess.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to know the basic of the basics, that is, **how to call a function**, you should first read a C book (suggested [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language))

and then try to understand something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int PlayGuess(char solution)
{
    printf("hello from function, you passed me the %c character", solution);
    return 42; // Return value 42
}

int main(void) {

    int return_value = PlayGuess('A'); // I passed the 'A' character to the function
    // return_value is now 42

    return 0;
}
```

where

1) A function is declared AND defined

2) The function is called by providing the required arguments

3) The function returns a value

Comment: Suggestion: do also something with the A argument.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of your function is `int`. You have to store its return value in an `int` type variable in `main`. Since it expects an argument of type `char`, you need to pass a `char` argument to it

```
int main() 
{
    int return_val;
    char solution;  

    //Do something

    return_val = PlayGuess(solution);
}
```

Comment: better comment out the `...` statements ;)